# Issue Testing react-native with useCallback

Tags: react-native, testing, react-redux, react-hooks

I'm setting up tests for a react-native app. I'm using [react-native-testing-library](https://github.com/callstack/react-native-testing-library) and redux.

But i'm hitting a problem.

When the redux state got updated, inside my render test function, the component is re-rendered as expected but the useCallback deps doesn't seems to be updated !

As deps are not updated inside useCallbacks Hooks, my tests fails....

```
export const ListComponent = () => {
  const data = useSelector(myDataSelector);
  const onEndReached = useCallback(() => {
    if(data && data.length){
      // Do something
    }
  }, [data]);
  return <List />
}
```

Running this on a device or a simulator works well, data get updates inside useCallback.

But with test, data is not updated...

Need some help here ...

Thanks

Comment: Hi. Did you manage to solve your issue?